# Is there a way to see a database create by SQLiteAsyncConnection class

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm using SQLiteAsyncConnection in my project to hold my data locally. I would like to see the data inside its tables like using sql server maybe or some tool like that. I've tried where it was created and to open that .db file with sql server but I didn't managed to find it's location

this is how I create the db

```
var path = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "AppointmentsDB.db");
                db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(path);
```

I have tried printing the path or

```
db.DatabasePath
```

but it gives me a relative path something like this

```
/data/data/com.companyname.appointments
```

and I don't know that it's relative to

Now my question is.. is it possible to open that SQLite database with a "visual" tool like sql server 2019? If now then what would you suggest me to use so I can also see that data from sql server 2019?

Comment: yes, there are many tools for managing SQLite dbs.  Google it.  You will need to use adb to copy the file from your device to the desktop before you can open it.

Comment: And how can I find the full path to my database?

Comment: you have the path, it's relative to the root of the Android file system

Answer (score 1):

1. You can execute "adb pull" to remove the database file from the emulator and put it on your regular hard drive. Similar to "adb pull /data/data/com.companyname.appointments/databases/xxx.db".
2. If you want to view directly, you need to root your emulator.

Comment: For more more in depth explanations check this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0448269e-9dc5-4320-88a0-641ae0d01d1f/how-i-can-copy-my-sqlite-database-from-device-to-pc?forum=xamarinforms